# Make multiprocessing Pool to use free cores if available

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I have the following piece of code that uses a Pool of workes to perform some operations.

```
def my_func( args ):
    
    low_index = args[0][0]
    up_index  = args[0][1]
    
    params    = args[1][0]
    A         = args[1][1]
    B         = args[1][2]
    
    print( "PID:", mp.current_process() )    
        
    for k in range( low_index, up_index ):
        
        a = params[k]
        # what if np.dot uses multi-threading?
        A = a*A + ( np.dot( A , B ) )*( np.dot( B, B ) )
        B = a*B + ( np.dot( B , A ) )*( np.dot( A, A ) )
    
    return A,B

if __name__ == '__main__':     
        
    ts = time()       
            
    import numpy as np
    params                 = np.linspace( 1, 10, 1000 )
    
    n_dim                  = 1000
    
    # the arrays A,B get modified with each call to the worker
    A                      = np.random.rand( n_dim, n_dim )
    B                      = np.random.rand( n_dim, n_dim )
    
    C                      = np.random.rand( 5*n_dim, 5*n_dim )
    D                      = np.random.rand( 5*n_dim, 5*n_dim )

    ncpus                  = psutil.cpu_count( logical=False )
    number_processes       = ncpus - 1
    total_items            = params.shape[0]  
    n_chunck               = int( ( total_items )/number_processes )
    intervals              = [ [ k*n_chunck, (k+1)*n_chunck ] for k in range( number_processes )   ]
    intervals[ -1 ][ -1 ]  = total_items          
   
    from itertools import repeat    
    objs_  = list( repeat( ( params,
                             copy.deepcopy( A  ), 
                             copy.deepcopy( B  ), 
                           ) , number_processes - 1 ) )
    objs_.append( ( params,
                 copy.deepcopy( C  ), 
                 copy.deepcopy( D  ), 
               )  )
    args_l = []
    
    for k in range( number_processes ):
        args_l.append( [ intervals[k] , objs_[k] ]  )
                
    
    pool        = mp.Pool( processes = ncpus )
    results     = pool.map( my_func, args_l  )
    
    pool.close()  
    pool.join()
    
    print( time() - ts )
```

The last process (involving the C and D arrays) will take considerably longer than the rest; therefore, I want that once the other processes are done, the remaining process (the one with bigger dimensions of the array) can make efficient use of all available free cores. However, I am observing that the CPU usage stays around 20% (In my machine I use 5 cores out of 6) for the last process, therefore being highly inefficient in the remaining operations. Is there a good way to fix that?

Comment: One thread can only run on one core, and only one python thread can run at a time per python process. Some numpy operations use multiple threads (non python threads) that can run in parallel in a given python process, but other than that, each process only gets one thread at a time (and therefore one core).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as you are mentioning the threads of Numpy and Scipy, isn't that supposed to create racing conditions? As I understand it, Numpy and Scipy routines that release the GIL would look for available threads, and if this process does this individually, this is expected to lead to inefficient performance (if I am not mistaken).  The multiprocessing module is said to be thread-safe, but if extensive use of Numpy is made on its process, isn't that an issue?

Comment: 2 things... 1. Numpy and scipy create their own threads, so as long as your code is thread safe, they are as well (under the hood, parallelism is actually handled by blas/lapack or whatever numpy was built with). You probably are already using parallel processing with numpy without knowing it (it's generally enabled by default). 2. `multiprocessing` is thread safe in that it is totally separate from other processes, but if you also then create multiple threads from that process, you do have to make sure your code is thread safe.

Comment: Generally keeping a processor "fed" with enough work to do is about breaking down the job into chunks that are small enough that no individual process takes too long, but long enough that the overhead of creating the new process isn't a significant proportion of the compute time. It is all but inevitable that at the end of your list of "chunks" that some cores will finish up before others. If each "chunk" is relatively short, then the amount of wasted time is minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In the example above, suppose I am operating on a 32 core machine (16 of which are physical), and my chuncks list contains 15 chunck, with each of the similar length for the params array. Then I am creating 15 new processes, one on each physical core, and keep the maximum allowed threads for numpy/scipy equal to 1. This makes a max of CPU usage of 50%, but I have testes that, for example making the max of threads equal to 2 (per process) actually makes the calculation slower. What is this related to then? What would be the optimal choice for a code like the one above?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out your code example, and I think you're making it way too complicated... `pool.map` has a `chunksize` parameter that you should use. Basically if you were `map`ing over a list of 10000 elements, setting a chunksize of 100 would compute 100 batches of 100 elements. To that end however, numpy matrix operations are going to take the longest in your `my_func`, and that's already multi-threaded by default. If you try to run multiples at a time, you'll end up with many times more threads than cores, and they'll just add overhead

Comment: also when you send something to a child process (like arguments being sent to a pool worker), a copy is made inherently, so no need to `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: So, in summary, the above code is likely to be way more efficient by serialization, just letting all numpy operations to use the maximum number of threads, and looping over the parameters as in a normal loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237466/discussion-between-aaron-and-zarathustra).